# Embed Instagram Feed with Hashtag and Username

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I want to embed an Instagram feed to my website from my Instagram account but only include posts with a certain hashtag.  I tried some 3rd party widgets but they only provide a feed with username *or* hashtag but not both.  I registered for the Instagram API and registered a new client.  I want to access:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER_ID/media/recent/?client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

The problem is that as long as I didn't start a submission, I cannot access the URL above.  I cannot start a submission because when I choose `I want to display my Instagram posts on my website`, I only get the option `I do not need to submit for review for this use case`.

Any ideas how I will be able to integrate the feed with hashtag and my username on my website?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be to use something like http://instafeedjs.com/, it's a jQuery plugin that lets you select a user and filter by hashtags. Unfortunately if you were looking to filter multiple hashtags you'll run into trouble because the Instagram API only allows for 1 hashtag at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the plugin but there are two problems. I have to generate an access token to fetch the images from my account. But first of all it doesn't work I only get a 404 error. And second I think it's not good to have the access token visible in the js on my site, or am I wrong?

Comment: Now it's working. I got the wrong user id. But the second problem is remaining. According to this site http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token
the access token should not be visible

Comment: And as far as I can see it's not possible to get images by user and hashtag.

Comment: Yeah you would be smart to not have your access token visible for someone to find since it gives access to your account's feed. Without it I'm not sure you'll get the ability to do user and # though.

Comment: from their github page - IMPORTANT! Instafeed.js will stop working completely on March 2, 2020.

Comment: Does anyone know of a good alternative to Instafeed, starting in March?